# Internal Mic not recording sound in ASUS RoG

Tags: 20.04, asus, microphone

(Note: Posting here after getting no reply from unix stackexchange)

I recently bought an ASUS ROG PC thinking 'what could go wrong'. Perhaps now I am paying the price.. at least I got over the hurdle of hDPI. Now, I got a internal microphone problem.

- The internal microphone works in Windows, does not in Ubuntu
- System indeed reports microphone, but only dead silence could be recorded
- Tried restarting alsa & pulseaudio, meddling with alsamixer volumes, ineffective
- One strange thing: alsamixer shows NVIDIA initially, and I have to switch to Realtek to control the sounds
- Looking at what happens right after enabling the microphone, it seems like adaptive audio is filtering any signal - but I don't know

How do I fix this? Thank you!

EDIT: No one? :<

Comment: I think it was a corruption of some sort. After some (painful) re-installs, it fixed itself and now it works. Clearly, the input method was overly adapting to some huge sound coming in when mic is unmuted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps.

- Install pavucontrol:
  sudo apt install -y pavucontrol`
- Run it with:
  sudo pavucontrol
- Now, look for "Input Devices" tab
- Unlock the channels by clicking on the lock icon
- Set the right-front channel to silence

Comment: Sorry, I tried it and it does not work.